What is a definition of 'Renderable canvas' in a context of web based test automation
In description of 'location' property of Selenium WebDriver the term 'Renderable canvas' is used:

property location: dict
The location of the element in the renderable canvas.

Link: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.location
What is the definition of that term?
